# SparkBQ connector issue: IllegalArgumentException: Wrong bucket: bq_temporary_folder, expected bucket: null

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataproc

I need help figuring out why my Spark job that is using the spark-bigquery-connector failed during the write step to temporaryGcsBucket.
Here is the Spark code that is trying to write the data to BQ table

```
  outDF.write
    .format("bigquery")
    .option("temporaryGcsBucket", "bq_temporary_folder")
    .option("parentProject", "user_project")
    .option("table", "user.destination_table")
    .mode(SaveMode.Overwrite)
    .save()
```

Here is the error log:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Wrong bucket: bq_temporary_folder, in path: gs://bq_temporary_folder/.spark-bigquery-application_1605725797163_1966-6f6cfc35-543b-4138-ae0e-649ce7c2ae56, expected bucket: null
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystem.checkPath(GoogleHadoopFileSystem.java:89)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.makeQualified(FileSystem.java:581)
    at com.google.cloud.hadoop.fs.gcs.GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.makeQualified(GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase.java:454)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.<init>(FileOutputCommitter.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputCommitter.<init>(FileOutputCommitter.java:103)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputCommitter.<init>(ParquetOutputCommitter.java:43)
    at org.apache.parquet.hadoop.ParquetOutputFormat.getOutputCommitter(ParquetOutputFormat.java:442)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupCommitter(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:100)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupCommitter(SQLHadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:40)
    at org.apache.spark.internal.io.HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.setupTask(HadoopMapReduceCommitProtocol.scala:217)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.executeTask(FileFormatWriter.scala:226)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.$anonfun$write$15(FileFormatWriter.scala:175)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:405)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I'm using the SparkBQ connector **spark-bigquery-with-dependencies_2.12-0.18.0.jar** and the GCS connector **gcs-connector-hadoop2-2.0.0-shaded.jar**.

I do not think it's permission issue. Since the Spark job was able to write to the same GCS bucket by calling *rdd.saveAsTextFile()*

When I checked the GoogleHadoopFileSystem code, the *expected bucket: null*  error message occurred because the *rootBucket* in the GoogleHadoopFileSystemBase class is not set.
But I don't know how I can get this field initialized in the first place.

Someone told me that there might be a mismatch GCS connector version between my Spark job and the Spark cluster. Even after confirming that the Spark job was using the GCS connector library configured for the Spark cluster, the job still failed.

I'm running out of idea what to try at this point.

Thank you in advance for any advices/helps.

Comment: Spark version ??

Comment: Spark version 2.4.0.

Comment: Are you using Dataproc? If not, can you please upgrade the GCS connector to version 2.1.6?

Comment: I'm not using Dataproc. I'm running it as Spark job.
I'm waiting for the team to upgrade the GCS connector on the Spark cluster, but I don't know when it will happen.
Is this issue related to the mismatch connector version?

Comment: Are there any updates with the new GCS connector? Is the issue persists?

Comment: The team is testing the new connector on a test cluster. So I'm waiting until they become available.

Comment: Hi @Wilma , are there any updates?